# PHP MAILER Warning: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string

Tags: php, phpmailer

am using phpmailer to send mail, which is sending mail but i keep getting this error, any   help is appreciated,

> Warning: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in
>   ........../mail/class.phpmailer.php on line
>   773
>
> Warning: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in
>   ........../mail/class.phpmailer.php on line
>   773
>
> Warning: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in
>   ........../mail/class.phpmailer.php on line
>   773

here is line 771 downwards

```
771     protected function addOrEnqueueAnAddress($kind, $address, $name)
772        {
773            $address = trim($address);
774            $name = trim(preg_replace('/[\r\n]+/', '', $name)); //Strip breaks and trim
775            if (($pos = strrpos($address, '@')) === false) {
776                // At-sign is misssing.
777                $error_message = $this->lang('invalid_address') . " (addAnAddress $kind): $address";
778                $this->setError($error_message);
779                $this->edebug($error_message);
780                if ($this->exceptions) {
781                    throw new phpmailerException($error_message);
782                }
783                return false;
784            }
```

Comment: Then it would be USEFUL to know what you are passing as a parameter in the `$address` function parameter. But that must have been the first thing you checked, right?

Comment: I dont think it would be a big guess to say you are passing an object and not a simple string variable

Comment: The most important DEBUGGING Tool is that **stuff between your ears**, oh and your eyes

Comment: thats the code for **class.phpmailer.php** as it is in https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/class.phpmailer.php no modifications

Comment: **YES** And it expects `$address` to be a STRING and not an OBJECT. **Show us the code that calls this method**